# HTML spacing between images

Tags: html

I have a loop, shown below, which shows a number of images, stacked one on top of each other.
How can I add a vertical space above/below each of these images so that they are not touching?

```
if (sizeof($connections))
{
    foreach($connections as $current_user_profile)
        echo "<li><img src='$current_user_profile.jpg' align='left' /></a>";
}
```

Comment: add a <br /> after </a>

Comment: That isn't valid HTML? Also note that the `img align` attribute was removed in HTML5 and will not work, use CSS instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply margin to the images. This CSS will do it:

```
img {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do it like

```
if (sizeof($connections))
{
    foreach($connections as $current_user_profile)
        echo "<li><img src='$current_user_profile.jpg' align='left' style='margin-top: 10px;' /></a>";
}
```